# import XML in google spreadsheet with specified tag

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-docs

one more problem.
I have following structure of XML:

```
<player>
 <id>12</id>
 <name>pl_name</name>
 <experience>
  <points>147</points>
  <level>10</level>
 </experience>
 <skills>
  <fight>0.00</fight>
  <defend>3.45</defend>
 </skills>
</player>
```

i want to be written just fight skill in my gdoc.
so something like this:

```
=ImportXML("http://api.mysite.net/xml/user/id/"&C5; "/*(what here?)")
```

If it's possible :)
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ImportXML("http://api.mysite.net/xml/user/id/"&C5; "//player/skills/fight")
```

thanks :)